# Linux shell command to read/print file chunk by chunk

Tags: linux, file, shell

Is there a standard Linux command i can use to read a file chunk by chunk?
For example, i have a file whose size is 6kB. I want to read/print the first 1kB, and then the 2nd 1kB ...
Seems cat/head/tail wont work in this case.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dd will do it

```
dd if=your_file of=output_tmp_file bs=1024 count=1 skip=0
```

And then skip=1 for the second chunk, and so on.

You then just need to read the output_tmp_file to get the chunk.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it looks definitely promising. After i did:
dd if=eco.log bs=1024 count=1 skip=1 (I prefer output to stdout)

I got the information i want followed by:
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
508 bytes (508 B) copied, 6.6e-05 seconds, 7.7 MB/s

How can i ignore above I/O stat info? I maned dd, and there isn't such silient option.

Comment: Never mind, just found out those I/O stat are outputted to stderr. I can easily ignore those. Thanks all!

Answer (score 7):

You could do this with `read -n` in a loop:

```
while read -r -d '' -n 1024 BYTES; do
    echo "$BYTES"
    echo "---"
done < file.dat
```

Comment: how can I make it print in hex?

Answer (score 2):

`split` can split a file into pieces by given byte count

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to actually *read* a text file?  Like with your eyes?  Try `less` or `more`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `fmt`

eg 10bytes

```
$ cat file
a quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
good lord , oh my gosh

$ tr '\n' ' '<file | fmt -w10 file
a quick
brown fox
jumps
over
the lazy
dog good
lord , oh
my gosh
```

each line is 10 characters. If you want to read the 2nd chunk, pass it to tools like awk ..eg

```
$ tr '\n' ' '<file |  fmt -w10 | awk 'NR==2' # print 2nd chunk
brown fox
```

To save each chunk to file, (or you can use `split` with -b )

```
$ tr '\n' ' '<file |  fmt -w10 | awk '{print $0 > "file_"NR}'
```