# A better alternative to chunking a file line by line

Tags: bash, shell, awk, compression, bigdata

The closest question which I found to have any resemblance to what I am asking is here.
[Linux shell command to read/print file chunk by chunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389249/linux-shell-command-to-read-print-file-chunk-by-chunk)

### **My system conditions**

1. A cluster with a shared filesystem served over NFS
2. Disk capacity = 20T

### **File Description**

Standard FASTQ files used in large scale genomics analysis

1. A File containing n lines or n/4 records.
2. Typical file size is 100 - 200 G
3. I keep them as bunzips with a compression value of -9 (when specifying to bzip2)

When analyzing these files, I use SGE for my jobs therefore I analyze them in chunks of 1M or 10M records.

So when dividing the file I use

```
<(bzcat [options] filename) > Some_Numbered_Chunk
```

to divide these files up into smaller chunks for efficient processing over SGE.

### **Problems**

1. When dividing these files up, this chunking step represents a significant amount of computation time.
   i. Because there are a lot of records to sift through.
   ii. Because NFS IO is not as fast as the bzcat pipe which I am using for chunking so NFS is limiting the speed at which a file can be chunked.
2. Many times I have to analyze almost 10-20 of these files together and unpacked all of them aggregate to nearly 1-2T of data. So on a shared system this is a very big limiting step and causes space cruches as others have to wait for me to go back and delete these files. (No I cannot delete all of these files as soon as the process has finished because I need to manually make sure that all processes completed successfully)

So how can I optimize this using other methods to lower the computation time, and also so that these chunks use up lesser amounts of hard disk space?

Answer (score 0):

Several options spring to mind:

1. Increase your bandwidth of your storage (add more physical links).
2. Store your data in smaller files.
3. Increase your storage capacity so you can reduce your compression ratio.
4. Do your analysis off your shared storage (get the file over NFS, write to a local disk).